# prove that a graph with degree $\frac{n-1}{2}$ has a diameter of at most 2

Tags: combinatorics, logic, graph-theory

I try to solve the following:

> let $G$ be a simple graph with minimum degree of $\frac{(n-1)}{2}$ with $n$ vertices. prove that $G$ is connected and that the diameter of $G$ is at most $2$

I Know how to prove that the graph is connected -

> assume that we take some connected component K, for each $v\in k$ we have that $deg(v)=\frac{n-1}{2}$ so that means that we have at least $\frac{n-1}{2}+1=\frac{n+1}{2}$ vertices which implies that if we have more then one connected component we have more than $n$ vertices - a contradiction

But  how to prove the diameter part?
my way of thinking was to compute how many vertices can I reach after "two moves" trail but I got some not conclusive result:

$$\frac{n-1}{2} + \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot ( \frac{n-1}{2} -1)$$
$$\Downarrow$$ 
$$=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}$$ which is **not** bigger than $n-1$ for all $n$ I know how to work around this but this seems "lame" I am sure there is some other elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a relatively simple argument.

Choose two vertices $a$ and $b$. We want to show that there is a path between them of at most $2$ edges.

If $a$ and $b$ are connected, we are done.

If $a$ and $b$ are not connected, then each of them has at least $\frac{n-1}2$ edges connecting to the remaining $n-2$ vertices. By pigeonhole principal, there must be at least one vertex connected to both. This gives us a path connecting $a$ and $b$ of length $2$.